# Using CProgressCtrl::SetRange32 to increase a range

Tags: mfc, progress-bar

I have a situation where I start off with an initial range and then want to extend the range.

But if I call `SetRange32` with the increased size the progress bar resets to 0 and then I have to set the position again.

I don't want it to reset to 0. If anything, I want it to dynamically re-adjust based on the the new range and retain the existing position.

Is this possible?

Calling SetRange and then SetPos to get back on track is a visually ugly solution.

Comment: _"But if I call SetRange32 with the increased size the progress bar resets to 0"_ -- I cannot reproduce. I have created a `CProgressBarCtrl`, called `SetRange32(0,1000)` and `SetPos(500)` in `OnInitDialog()`. When I call `SetRange32(0,2000)` later, the position is **not** reset to 0. It stays at 500 (visually 1/4 length of total progress bar).

Comment: @zett42 Odd that it works for you and not me.

Comment: Can you reproduce with a [mcve]? I'm fairly certain that `SetRange32()` and `SetPos()` don't affect each other as long as you don't set the range such that the current position would be out-of-range.

Comment: @zett42 I am going to leave it. Based in the answer provided to me I have a simple working way forward with easier to manage logic anyway. :)

Comment: @zett42 It is possible I had a bug that caused it to set the position to an unexpected value. But using percentages for the positioning instead has simplified things. So I am happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd set a very large fixed size with `CProgressCtrl::SetRange32` and then use `CProgressCtrl::SetPos` dealing yourself with a virtual size and a virtual position.

This is the idea:

You want:

- `SetRange32(100)`
- `SetPosition(50)`   // position 50% (absolute position 50)
- `SetRange32(200)`   // position should decrease to 25% (absolute position still 50)
                   // (I suppose that's what you want)
- `SetPosition(60)`   // position 30 % (absolute position 60)

Works but is ugly.

Do this instead:

- `SetRange32(BIGRANGE);`
- `SetPosition(BIGRANGE * (50 / 100))` position 50% (absolute position 50)
- now we want another range `NEWRANGE` no `SetRange32` needed
- `SetPosition((BIGRANGE / NEWRANGE) * (50 / 100))`
- `SetPosition((BIGRANGE / NEWRANGE) * (60 / 100))`

Of course your you need to take care of integer division or use floating point.

## Update (from @ajtruckle)

Or, just leave the progress bar with the default range of `0 - 100` and work out the percentages accordingly. No need to change the range at all.

Comment: Thanks. Having looked at your answer it became apparent that I did not actually need to use a "range" as such and just stick with the progress bar representing the percentage (0 to 100). So all is good now.:)